# MySQL column wise category counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
id name center1    center2   cnter3
1  abc  baroda     bhopal    chennai
2  pqr  amhedabad  Surat     kolkata
3  nml  bhopal     chennai   Surat
4  fts  baroda     Surat     Baroda
```

I want a result Like:

```
         center1 center2  center3
Baroda     2       0        1   
Ahmedabad  1       0        0
bhopal     1       1        0
chennai    0       1        1
Kolkatta   0       0        1
Surat      0       2        1.
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

This will require a handful of subquery joins. First, you need to get all the distinct values from the three columns, which would be done with a `UNION` of queries of each column.

That distinct list must then be `LEFT JOIN`ed against a trio of subqueries which pulls the counts per value from each of the three columns.

Finally, a `COALESCE()` replaces NULLs with 0.

```
SELECT 
  allvalues.value,
  /* LEFT JOIN will result in NULL for non-existent values, so coalesce into 0 */
  COALESCE(c1.counts, 0) AS center1,
  COALESCE(c2.counts, 0) AS center2,
  COALESCE(c3.counts, 0) AS center3
FROM
  (
    /* UNIONs gets distinct vals from all columns */
    SELECT center1 AS value FROM yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT center2 AS value FROM yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT center3 AS value FROM yourtable
  ) AS allvalues
  /* LEFT JOIN the list of distinct possible values against a count per value for each column */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT center1, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM yourtable GROUP BY center1
  ) c1 ON allvalues.value = c1.center1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT center2, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM yourtable GROUP BY center2
  ) c2 ON allvalues.value = c2.center2
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT center3, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM yourtable GROUP BY center3
  ) c3 ON allvalues.value = c3.center3
```

#### [Here is a working demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9366e/1), because I guess I'm feeling extra charitable tonight.

Comment: +1 Charitable? If I make a post asking for $100, can I count on you to come through?

Comment: Using a similar union trick as my answer, but the joins make it more complicated according to the output of sqlfiddle's execution plan. Still, I like the explanation and the use of COALESCE.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I typically don't look at the approval rating or reputation, just the quality of the question and whether the OP is lazy.

Answer (score 2):

I used [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d9a1/9) to trasform your table's text representation into a sequence of CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements:

```
CREATE TABLE CenterCodes
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(3), `center1` varchar(9), `center2` varchar(7), `center3` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO CenterCodes
    (`id`, `name`, `center1`, `center2`, `center3`)
VALUES
    (1, 'abc', 'baroda', 'bhopal', 'chennai'),
    (2, 'pqr', 'amhedabad', 'Surat', 'kolkata'),
    (3, 'nml', 'bhopal', 'chennai', 'Surat'),
    (4, 'fts', 'baroda', 'Surat', 'Baroda')
;
```

Try the following query.  The inner `UNION` produces multiple rows per string value with NULLs for 2 of the 3 columns on each set.  Those NULLs are then eliminated by the aggregate `SUM()`s in the outer query, collapsing the rowset down to one row per string value.

```
SELECT
  centername,
  SUM(CASE WHEN centername = center1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS center1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN centername = center2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS center2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN centername = center3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS center3
FROM (
  SELECT
    center1 AS centername,
    center1,
    NULL AS center2,
    NULL AS center3
  FROM CenterCodes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    center2 AS centername,
    NULL AS center1,
    center2,
    NULL AS center3
  FROM CenterCodes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    center3 AS centername,
    NULL AS center1,
    NULL AS center2,
    center3
  FROM CenterCodes
) AS Centers
GROUP BY centername;
```

Comment: +1 Tricky, but efficient solution.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm too tired right now to explain why it works. The NULL trick feels particularly murky. The local SQL guru in my office taught me this technique and I'm glad to try it out on SO :)

Comment: Then I'll edit in a little explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is also important. I remembered why we use nulls instead of the column values. if you include the `center1` values in the computed `center1` three times (one set of values for each unioned query), the counts returned by the sum expression for `center1` would be three times as high. Instead of NULL, you could as well use `''` as the placeholder, or any value you know is absent from the base data.

Comment: Right - aggregate functions eliminate nulls.

Comment: But it doesn't rely on NULLs to produce the correct result. Replace the NULLs with `''` in my query and you will still get the correct result.